# Node - SQLite resolve promise from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am having trouble with Node asynchronous behavior, I have the following snippet:

```
async function f(db, id) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      logger.log("A");
      db.run('INSERT INTO s(a,b,c,d) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', ['a', 'b', 'c', 0],
            function(err) {
               console.log("B");
               if(err) {
                  console.error(`Err:\n\t${err}`);
                  reject(err);
               }
               db.run('UPDATE t SET a = ? WHERE id = ?', [this.lastID, id],
                     function(err) {
                        console.log("C");
                        if(err) {
                           console.log(`Err:\n\t${err}`);
                           reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve("Done!");
                     }, resolve, reject, id);
            }, resolve, reject, db, id);
   });
   console.log("D");
}
```

It's a simple SQLite based app, the idea is to insert an entry on table S, and then update an entry on table T based on the return value(ID) from the first insert query, however I am not sure how to resolve the returned promise from inside the callback.
When calling this function, the promise never resolves and eventually gets reject with null.

Calling it with:

```
async function g(db) {
   var p = f(db, "testid").catch(function(err) { console.log("ERROR: ${err}"); });
   var ret = await p;
   console.log(`ret: ${ret}`);
   return ret
}
```

Results in:

```
A
D
ERROR: null
ret: undefined
```

I am pretty sure the problem here is questionable asynchronous design by my part, so I have two questions.

1 - Why doesn't "B" or "C" ever gets printed.

2 - What would be the proper way to structure this?

Any material on proper Node design would also be highly appreciated, I love Node.js, but I think I am quite bad at it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to await the internal async functions. or the original DB.run.